I need to expand (vectorize) a 3D object in illustrator, but when I flatten or expand, the object still pixelates
I would like to expand a 3D item to vectorize it; however, when I expand appearance, it still pixelates. When I flatten transparency, it just creates a flat, white, rasterized rectangle. At this point, I don't know what to do, and I need to make it a vector (not raster) because it's for print purposes. What can I do instead?


Hit the drop down button next to the Render with Ray Tracing icon in the 3D and Materials dialog (top right). This will open the rendering options drop down menu

Select the Render as Vector option

Hit the Render button at the bottom of the dialog


Now when you Expand Appearance, it will be vector.

